# Udemy: Collection of frequent bookmarks for a course?

Tags: udemy

In every course in Udemy, there are bookmark hints such as this:

[image: Udemy Bookmark Hint]

A vast majority of learners seem to have bookmarked those moments, and for a valid reason -- there's often a new concept explained at those moments.

Yet, in my course page, under Bookmarks, I can only see **my own personal bookmarks**.

[image: Udemy My Bookmarks]

I'd like to see a collection of all the gray bookmark-hints as bookmarks. Is there a way to enable this?